# How to scrape all of the data from the website?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

My code only giving me 44 links data instead of 102. Can Someone say me why it is Extracting like that?I would appreciate your help.How can i extract it properly???

```
import scrapy
class ProjectItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    owned = scrapy.Field()
    Revenue2014 = scrapy.Field()
    Revenue2015 = scrapy.Field()
    Website = scrapy.Field()
    Rank = scrapy.Field()
    Employees = scrapy.Field()
    headquarters = scrapy.Field() 
    FoundedYear = scrapy.Field()
```

class ProjectSpider(scrapy.Spider):

```
name = "cin100"
allowed_domains = ['cincinnati.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.cincinnati.com/story/money/2016/11/26/see-which-companies-16-deloitte-100/94441104/']

def parse(self, response):

    # get selector for all 100 companies
    sel_companies = response.xpath('//p[contains(.,"click or tap here.")]/following-sibling::p/a')

    # create request for every single company detail page from href
    for sel_companie in sel_companies:
        href = sel_companie.xpath('./@href').extract_first()
        url = response.urljoin(href)
        request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_company_detail)
        yield request

def parse_company_detail(self, response):           

    # On detail page create item
    item = ProjectItem()
    # get detail information with specific XPath statements
    # e.g. title is the first paragraph
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[1]//text()').extract_first().rsplit('-')[1]
    # e.g. family owned has a label we can select
    item['owned'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[contains(.,"Family owned")]/text()').extract_first()  
item['Revenue2014'] ='$'+response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[contains(.,"2014")]/text()').extract_first().rsplit('$')[1]
item['Revenue2015'] ='$'+response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[contains(.,"$")]/text()').extract_first().rsplit('$')[1]
    item['Website'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p/a[contains(.,"www.")]/@href').extract_first()
item['Rank'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[contains(.,"rank")]/text()').extract_first()
item['Employees'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[contains(.,"Employ")]/text()').extract_first()
item['headquarters'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[10]//text()').extract()
item['FoundedYear'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[contains(.,"founded")]/text()').extract()
    # Finally: yield the item
    yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking closer at the output of scrapy you'll find that starting after a few dozen of requests they get redirected like shown below:

```
DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.cincinnati.com/get-access/?return=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cincinnati.com%2Fstory%2Fmoney%2F2016%2F11%2F27%2Ffrischs-restaurants%2F94430718%2F> from <GET http://www.cincinnati.com/story/money/2016/11/27/frischs-restaurants/94430718/>
```

The page that gets requested says: **We hope you have enjoyed your complimentary access.**

So it looks like they offer only limited access to anonymous users. You probably need to register to their service to get full access to the data.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few potential problems with your xpaths:

1. it's usually a bad idea to make xpaths look for text that's on a page. Text can change from one minute to the next. The layout and html structure is much more long lived.
2. using 'following-siblings' is also a last-resort xpath feature that is quite vulnerable to slight changes on the website.

What I would be doing instead:

```
# iterate all paragraphs within the article:
for para in  response.xpath("//*[@itemprop='articleBody']/p"):
    url = para.xpath("./a/@href").extract()
    # ... etc
```

`len( response.xpath("//*[@itemprop='articleBody']/p"))` gives me the expected 102 by the way.

You might have to filter the URLs to remove non-company urls like the on labeled with "click or tap here"